# turn a :string from a database into a clickable link in a view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that takes in a URL and then a view that displays that entry. How do i make the view clickable, i.e. an active link?

I tried this but it isn't working. it displays the CSS of an active link but does nothing when clicked.

```
<td>
    <h3>Portfolio</h3>
    <h2><%= link_to @user.portfolio ,target: "_blank"  %></h2>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to with URL for is what you need

link_to @user.portfolio ,target: "_blank" , url_for: @user.portfolio)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for

Comment: so when i do this all it does is append "?target=_blank&url_for=apple.com" (a test url) to the URL but it won't launch the page. so URL is changing with the append but still staying on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
  <h3>Portfolio</h3>
  <h2><%= link_to "User portfolio link text", @user.portfolio, :target => "_blank" %></h2>
 </td>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: this is a hard code. i'm looking for the answer that uses a variable.

Comment: This was an example, you can change it to your variable, I have updated my answer for you to see

Answer (score 0):

This did it: `link_to @user.profile, "http://#{@user.profilel}"`

It was missing the "http://" and it could be prefixed with string interpolation.